# Visual Basic Debug in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, debug

I had a workbook created for me.

I made a mistake and deleted an entire row from the Master Page and now I am getting a debug error and `#REF!` on the UC-K sheet.

The error says `Run-Time Error '13': Type mismatch`.

When I Debug the following line is highlighted in Yellow:

```
If .Cells(R, NwsLastCol).Value = 0 Then
```

The whole code in that section is:

```
Public Sub HideRows(ByRef Ws As Worksheet)

    Dim R As Long

    ScreenAndEvents False
    With Ws
        .Rows.Hidden = False
        For R = NwsFirstRow To LastRow(NwsFirstCol, Ws)
            If .Cells(R, NwsLastCol).Value = 0 Then .Rows(R).Hidden = True
        Next R
    End With
    ScreenAndEvents True
End Sub
```

Please help!! :) I am willing to share the workbook if needed, but I'd like to know how to fix it myself as well.

Comment: Try adding the line `On Error Resume Next` after the line `Dim R As Long`. That will cause VBA to keep processing the code after encountering the cell containing the **#REF** error.

Comment: @Twisty that's very bad advice. `On Error Resume Next` just shoves whatever error you get, under the carpet, letting the code happily continue with bad/unknown values. **Handle** errors, don't **hide** them!

Comment: It's not going to be possible to assist you in debugging this without seeing a lot more of the workbook and the VBA code.  `NwsFirstRow` is not a built-in VBA object; it has to be a global object defined elsewhere in the custom VBA code.  By deleting that row, you've broken `NwsFirstRow` somehow. A `Type Mismatch` error in this context is pretty much impossible to debug without getting one's hands on the entire thing, since it could refer to `.Cells` or `.Value`.

Comment: When you press debug, it should hilight the code that throws the error. If you then hover your mouse on the R, you can see the value it last had before the debugger stopped the code. You'll need to look into what this is to find the row that throws in the error. Also, try recreating the rows you accidentally deleted, as its likely going to be necessary to solve your code.

Comment: Also NwsFirstRow and NwsFirstCol sound like they're a range. So it may just be a matter of redifining these ranges.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I completely agree errors should be handled appropriately; but for a user that obviously cannot maintain the code himself, there's a tradeoff between skipping a bad value and writing error-handling code that would...skip the bad value. To your point perhaps the Resume Next should be placed closer to the .Hidden method, followed by On Error Goto 0, but using Resume Next is a perfectly acceptable way of dealing with invalid values on the user's worksheet.

Comment: Restore from backup

Answer (score 0):

To avoid *Type Mismatches*

replace:

```
If .Cells(R, NwsLastCol).Value = 0
```

with:

```
If .Cells(R, NwsLastCol).Text = "0"
```